# Datetime convertion does not return desired value

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem when I convert `DateTime.Now` , which results in `05-11-2013 12:37:37` to `2013-11-05 12:37:37`. I tried the following ways;

```
DateTime dtn = DateTime.Now;
string ds = dtn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime dtnn = Convert.ToDateTime(ds);
dtn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But they both give me `05-11-2013` (dd-MM-yyyy) instead of `2013-11-05` (yyyy-MM-dd). The only thing that changes is the time, which has changed to `00:00:00`.

Does anyone know how I can convert to  this Format `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Comment: Which variable you output?

Comment: Little tip: how ToDateTime() can **guess** date format is "yyyy-MM-dd" instead of the current locale one?

Comment: second one does the job (first also), look: http://ideone.com/Cqeww2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps (Your second line of code should work as expected):

```
//To Convert the DateTime to a string with yyyy-MM-dd format
string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

//To Convert a string with yyyy-MM-dd format to a date
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**EDIT:**

As per comments, if your requirement is to compare dates you do not need any of the above. Compare dates as dates not as strings.

Comment: When I execute your first code, I get a yyyy-MM-dd string, but when I use your second part its a dd-mm-yyyy date again. I don't know why that is.

Comment: Those are two different examples. (1) - DateTime > To a string with a given format. (2) Formatted string to a DateTime. If you need to compare dates, you do NOT have to do any of the above but simply compare Date/DateTime not strings.

Comment: If I want to compare my datetime.now with a datetime value in my database , regardless of the format, I can just compare them?

Comment: Of course, yes. That is the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use the dtnn in a query to check between dates, that is why I want to convert it. dtnn is a dd-mm-yyyy as you can see in my picture.

Comment: `Date/DateTime` does not have a format. It is simply a Date. You `should be comparing Date/DateTime` *not formatted* `strings`. So, ignore what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the format in Convert.ToDateTime() by supplying an IFormatProvider, such as DateTimeFormatInfo.

You can read more about it here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here you have how to format a date:

DateTime.ToString("u")

Here you have the other formats you can use:

```
// This example displays the following output to the console:
//       d: 6/15/2008
//       D: Sunday, June 15, 2008
//       f: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15 PM
//       F: Sunday, June 15, 2008 9:15:07 PM
//       g: 6/15/2008 9:15 PM
//       G: 6/15/2008 9:15:07 PM
//       m: June 15
//       o: 2008-06-15T21:15:07.0000000
//       R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT
//       s: 2008-06-15T21:15:07
//       t: 9:15 PM
//       T: 9:15:07 PM
//       u: 2008-06-15 21:15:07Z
//       U: Monday, June 16, 2008 4:15:07 AM
//       y: June, 2008
//       
//       'h:mm:ss.ff t': 9:15:07.00 P
//       'd MMM yyyy': 15 Jun 2008
//       'HH:mm:ss.f': 21:15:07.0
//       'dd MMM HH:mm:ss': 15 Jun 21:15:07
//       '\Mon\t\h\: M': Month: 6
//       'HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz': 21:15:07.0000-07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Following links might help you..

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm